# Laplace method with "bad" zero set

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, geometric-measure-theory

It is well-known that if $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function with $\phi(0) = 0$, $\phi(x)>0$ if $x \neq 0$ and $D^2\phi(0) \geq 0$, then the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\phi(x)/2t}a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
has an asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow 0$ (obtained via the Laplace method). One can also calculate asymptotic expansions under other non-degeneracy conditions than $D^2\phi(0) \geq 0$ or in the case that the zero set of $\phi$ is a submanifold.

\Edit: I assume that $\phi$ and $a$ are smooth and that $a$ is compactly supported. However, if there are results/references where this is not the case, I would be interested in this case as well.

**Question: What if the critical set is arbitrary?**

- How bad can the critical set actually be?
- Under which assumptions on the critical set can we calculate (at least first order) asymptotic expansions? What kind of irregular sets can be taken here?

Comment: For the first question, not that any closed set can be the zero set of a smooth function.

Comment: To apply Laplace's method, I am under the impression that one requires certain regularity/non degeneracy conditions on $a(x)$ near to $x=0$, as well as global integrability conditions on $a$ ... is this implicitly assumed here or not? If so, could it be stated in the question, and if not, could you refer me to a reference where Laplace methods are considered with no regularity/degeneracy requirements are placed on a(x) near to 0? Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I made the appropriate edit.